# Template .Net Core Not Display Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I instal Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Entreprise,and then I instal .Net core SDK.
Why when I create a new project templet .Net core not displayed?
[image: This Image when i create a new project]

Comment: Try selecting **Templates** or **Visual C#** from tree..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using VS 2015 (says 2017 in your title), you probably need to install the "tool preview", for instance from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core). That did the trick for me back in the day, but I have since moved on to VS 2017, which feels a lot more core-ready out of the box.